# Events "beforeLinkSave" and "afterLinkSave"

Tags: spring-data-rest

I'm trying to understand how works the validation events in Sprind data REST. I understand that the event "beforeSave" runs just before I save a new information in the data source. I understand that the event "afterSave" is called at the end of storeing a new data. However, I don't understand when the events "beforeLinkSave" and "afterLinkSave" are run.

Does someone know the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have learned. The event "beforeLinkSave" is run before a new link is saved in an one to many or many to many relationship. "afterLinkSave" is similar. It is run after a new link is saved