# BeforeLinkSaveEvent and BeforeSaveEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I wanted to understand **events emitted in Spring Data Rest**.

I however discovered, that for saving there are two different kinds of events that are being emitted before "save": `BeforeSaveEvent` and `BeforeLinkSaveEvent`.

I cannot find any usable information about the differences between the two. On [another StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174050/events-beforelinksave-and-afterlinksave) I found this: *'The event `beforeLinkSave` is run before a new link is saved in an one to many or many to many relationship.'*

But this still doesn't tell me anything.

What kind of link is this about? REST link?

Foreign key constraints between database tables? Or something else?

Actually none of my two guesses seem to be logical. Maybe it would be easier to understand, if I'd see when does one of these events being emitted, but not the other one.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the JSON `http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address` corresponds to the field `Person.address` which is a reference.

```java
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String firstName, lastName;

  @OneToOne
  private Address address;
}

interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}

interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {}
```

```json
{
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
    },
    "address" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address"
    }
  }
}
```

The `BeforeLinkSaveEvent` is published in `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController#createPropertyReference()`.

## Reference

### [Item Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource)

> For every association of the domain type, we expose links named after the association property.

### [Association Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource)

> Spring Data REST exposes sub-resources of every item resource for each of the associations the item resource has. The name and path of the resource defaults to the name of the association property and can be customized by using @RestResource on the association property.